# Static global in memory

Tags: c

If there are 2 files in a project, using same name for static variable in both files, I didn't get linker error, but I want to know how two static variables named in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are not visible outside the C file where they are declared (or even outside the scope, with "C file" being "a particular file's file scope"). So there is no collision, and of course variable names don't matter in compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

The static variable is visible only within the module, it provides the local linkage.

1. The static variable inside the function it retains the value during function call.
2. The Static global variable or the function is visible only in the file or module that is declared.

---

The static specifier specifies both static storage duration and internal linkage.

Static storage duration. The storage duration is the entire execution of the program, and the value stored in the object is initialized only once, prior to main function.

Comment: in case of local static , variables with same name are represented with name mangling representation, but here I want to know how memory differentiates these two static variables in different files.